# How to get the :not selector to work when the element is buried inside of another element

Tags: html, css

Here is my html code that I am trying to manipulate.  I need to highlight the third cite block that says Chaz.  I am not supposed to use ids or classes to do this.

```
<aside id="left">
         <h2>What they're saying about us</h2>
         <blockquote title="testimonials">
           <p>&quot;CSS coding is endlessly fun. I have such a great time doing it.&quot;</p>
           <cite>DGMD student</cite>
         </blockquote>
         <blockquote>
           <p>&quot;I will be so glad when this assignment is over. &quot;</p>
           <cite>Another student</cite>
         </blockquote>
         <blockquote>
           <p>&quot;Do you really need so many classes and IDs after learning these cool selectors?&quot;</p>
           <cite>Chaz</cite>
        </blockquote>
  </aside>
```

Here is the css code that I created to do this but I am supposed to use the :not selector to complete this problem and every time that I try and use it nothing changes.

```
blockquote:last-of-type cite {
    background-color: purple;
    font-style: normal;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: *"I am not supposed to use ids or classes to do this."* - Interesting spec. Also because your CSS is working, and without classes or ids. I just don't see how you would need (or could even use) :not for this.

Comment: Unless you make it extra cumbersome by making all `cite`s purple and then resetting it for every one which is in :not the last block.

Comment: "Interesting spec."  Presumably this is a homework assignment or the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems to suggest that you apply a highlight to all `blockquote` elements and then use the CSS `:not()` selector to, erm, not select the last element when over-styling the first two.  Confused?  For example...

```
aside blockquote {
   background-color: pink;
}
aside blockquote:not(:last-of-type) {
    background-color: white; /* or page background-color */
}
```

Hope that helped :)

[See MDN > CSS3 > :not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot)

Comment: Thank you for your answers and help.  It is a confusing problem and I am not sure why the use of :not is required.

Comment: @cschwiers No probs. I know it's not that `:not()` is not not difficult once you got your head round it, it just feels like it isn't not tricky.  :D